# How Do I Hide Filename & extention in PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a url in this format: "sitename.com/folder/file.php". How do I make it a "sitename.com/randomhash" or "sitename.com/folder/randomhash" format?

I know I can use a GET & Switch system but I need the name to be unique and I need to be able to change it on the fly.

Comment: a random hash, and where should that page take you to? always same page?

Comment: please try to ask coherent questions.  show us what you've tried.

Comment: Why the hell do you need this? It don't offer any protection against things like CSRF or what not...

Comment: The OP is asking for mod_rewrite.

Comment: @Pekkafor a mod_rewrite that changes on each request...

Comment: Ok i just dont want people to know the path of certain files

Comment: Then use SEO friendly urls, that hides the ACTUAL path, what your trying to do is really complex and will make your app almost unmantainable.

Comment: Try this on for size: http://www.htmlist.com/how-to/a-simplemod_rewrite-tutorial/

Comment: you guys are really acting poor on this question i dont think i forced anyone to come here and comment if u have a problem look pass it. Thank you @Sammaye

Comment: @astonishin - I think that Sammaye's solution (mod_rewrite) is what you're looking for... The issue that many on here are bringing up is that hashing will either be random - in which case you'll have to keep a huge map hash->target redirects - or it will correlate with the target is some way (`md5($page_name)`) and won't enforce uniqueness... and it will look ugly to boot. @everyone: [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what your point is, but if you don't want you're visitors to know where your php-files are stored, I would recommend reading this:

[Tutorial for URL handling in PHP](http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=17250)

If you are having a website where people can download stuff, and you don't want people hotlinking your files, you could do the following steps (i'm not writing the code, I'm just going to give you a general idea):

1. People come to your website.
2. Person clicks on link because they want to download that particular file.
3. Person comes on page, where you have the opportunity to set a cookie with a random hash.
4. Simultaneously you put a value in a database, with the same hash and the filepath of the file they want to download.
5. On this page, they have to click "DOWNLOAD NOW!", where they are redirected to download.php.
6. In download.php you read the cookie, then match that with the database and get the filepath.
7. With the right php-headers, you can force download.php to download the file.

Important in this situation is that you set your settings of Apache (or whatever server you have) that downloading is not allowed unless 'localhost' is requesting it.